# External (Google, Microsoft) Login with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, duende-identity-server

When using Duende Identityserver with ASP.NET Identity there are 2 possibilities to add external logins :

- via ASP .NET Identity
- via Identityserver (AddOpenIdConnect)

What is the difference, what is recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

You would use ASP.NET Identity if you only have one application that you need to add authentication to.

If you want to support multiple applications (clients), you want to use tokens between applications, you want to be able to customize those JWT-tokens, then you should use IdentityServer. also, recomended if you are a company with many services and APIs.

IdentityServer does not deal with the actual users (the user-database, user-registrations, password-reset..) , so often it can be helpful to combine both.